# How can I view the contents of each partition in GParted?

Tags: gparted

In GParted, I'm trying to remove a partition that I'm not using (to make space for another operating system). The partition to remove is either dev/dev6 or dev/dev7. How can I view the contents of either partition (to make sure that I'm not accidentally deleting the wrong partition)?

I tried using the command `cd /dev/sda6` to view the partition `sda6`, but then I got the following output: `bash: cd: /dev/sda6: Not a directory`. Is there another way to view the contents of a specific partition?

Answer (score 2):

- You can use [MiniTool® Partition Wizard Bootable CD 7.6](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html).
  It can [explore volumes](http://www.partitionwizard.com/help/explore-partition.html) through its GUI.

  [image: MiniTool Partition Wizard]

(I for myself needed that option last week but I can't remember what software we were using.
It has the same ability. I think it was Paragon Partition Manager)

Comment: With the current version of MiniTool (11.0.1), you don't need the bootable CD verison. You can download the desktop version and explore the partitions without restarting. Very handy for figuring out what your partitions are since there's so little guidance online for actually figuring them out.

Answer (score 1):

GPartEd is made for dealing with partitions, not files. :)

Why not look at `dev6` and `dev7` in a terminal window instead of trying to do it in GPartEd?

More info on the terminal window included in the GPartEd LiveCD see [the GPartEd documentation](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=gparted-live-manual#gparted-live-working-with-terminal-window).

for info on navigating in Linux, check out:

- [Changing Drive In Linux](http://forums.opensuse.org/archives/sls-archives/archives-suse-linux/archives-hardware-support/369205-changing-drive-linux.html)
- [Change Directory in Terminal?](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/84323-change-directory-terminal.html)

Comment: How can I view the files in these partitions from the terminal window?

Comment: See the link I edited in.  If you are stuck, you may need to study up on some Linux basics like `cd` and `ls`. :)

Comment: The GParted documentation explains how to open a terminal window (and list the contents of a directory using the `ls` command), but I still want to know how to navigate to a specific partition and view its files. Would I simply use `cd dev/sda6` to navigate to a specific partition, or would another command be necessary?

Comment: I tried to navigate to `dev/sda6` and I got the following output: `bash: cd: dev/sda6: No such file or directory`

Comment: I used the command `cd dev/sda6` and I couldn't get to the partition using that command. Is it possible to navigate to a specific partition this way, or should I use  a different command?

Comment: Try including the root slash: `cd /dev/sda6`.  See my edit for a couple links that'll help you out.

Comment: I just tried that, and I got the following output: `bash: cd: /dev/sda6: Not a directory`. What should I do instead, since this command isn't working?